# Create column with a aggregated value

Tags: sql

I have one output table -table A which looks like this

| keys |
| --- |
| key 1 |
| key 2 |

```
SELECT keys
FROM table A
```

and i have another output table -table B which is result of aggregated function which is just having one row

| agg |
| --- |
| [1,2,3,4] |

```
SELECT agg_arr(columnX) as agg
FROM table A
```

what i want to do is i want to apply this aggregated result to all the rows in a new column in table A like this ( just a copy of the list )

| keys | col |
| --- | --- |
| key 1 | [1,2,3,4] |
| key 2 | [1,2,3,4] |

(both from the same table )
is there a way to do it? thank you

Comment: what's your dbms?

Comment: i am using clickhouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT t2.keys,t1.agg as col
FROM (
    SELECT agg_arr(columnX) as agg
    FROM tableA
) t1 CROSS JOIN tableA t2
```

Comment: thank you so much ,it would work perfectly , but  i have one query , as i am using clickhouse warehouse for storing table, it showing memory exceeding error because of cross join , can we do this some other way , if you know , please let me  know